# Set DPI of individual applications in Linux

Tags: linux, fonts, dpi

In order to test a Qt application I'm working on I need to run it with various DPI settings to see how it looks. I can change the DPI settings globally in a couple of ways (Appearance->Fonts or putting "Xft.dpi: NNN" in ~/.Xresources), but this is a pain.

Is there a simple way to do change the DPI setting only for a specific application instead of globally (affecting the entire desktop)?

Answer (score 1):

The DPI is set within X (on a per monitor basis), and, I believe, not available to be set on an application basis. So, no.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but yes, you could do it with a trick.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash                                                 
OLDDPI=$(xrdb -query | awk '/Xft.dpi/ {print $2}')
xrdb -merge <(echo "Xft.dpi: 108")
$* & disown
sleep 3
xrdb -merge <(echo "Xft.dpi: $OLDDPI")
```

You can save this as a script, and whenever you need to change DPI of an application

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:

1. Modify the .desktop file usually located in `/usr/share/applications/` and add `--force-device-scale-factor=1.5` option in the Exec command line.
2. Some applications like Zoom create a .conf file in ~/.config where you can specify a scale parameter: `ScaleFactor`.

If this was not sufficient, you'll probably find a solution here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI (Most solutions listed in this wiki are not Arch specific and work for various Desktop Environment)

https://superuser.com/a/1500746/1016302