# How to enable HiDPI support on Zoom.us linux client?

Tags: conferencing

Screen elements are too small to click or read on my 4K laptop screen. How do I make it obey Gnome scaling, which is set to 200%?

I'm on Fedora 29, but this should be the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

This issue also affects macbook retina display screens.

Comment: PSA: Using a scaleFactor >= 2 will for some reason make screen sharing buttons disappear (tested in Ubuntu 20.4.1, using ZOOM 5.4.6). Try using scaleFactor of 1.9 or 1.75 instead.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

An answer that does not require changing common files that may be changed by future installs:

Zoom currently creates a file named `zoomus.conf` under your `.config` folder in the user's home folder.

One of the settings is `ScaleFactor`, set to 1 by default. Set this to 2, and next time you start the application it will have appropriate-sized visuals.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my time

Comment: Thank you! Here's the oneliner: `perl -i -pe 's/scaleFactor=1/scaleFactor=2/' ~/.config/zoomus.conf`

Comment: This worked for me too, though I was having the opposite problem. My external monitor was scaled correctly, but the built-in laptop screen it was at double the size, and very big.  It was `scaleFactor=auto` and I changed it to `scaleFactor=1` - thanks, very helpful!

Comment: It doesn't have to be full number, ScaleFactor=2 made the icons kind of blurry, but ScaleFactor=1.5 works great for me

Comment: Doesn't work properly. I've got a huge window with huge buttons. (Kubuntu 20.04, Plasma Version: 5.18.5, with default env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0). `useSystemTheme=true` as mentioned below works fine.

Comment: `autoscale=true` worked for me, without changing `scaleFactor`

Comment: Adding a line 'ScaleFactor=2' in the ringcentral.conf file worked for me

Answer (score 86):

Recently I faced the opposite problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with Zoom 5.1.412382.0614: the UI was zoomed *in* and everything was too big.

The `scaleFactor` setting in the `zoomus.conf` file mentioned in the accepted answer was set to 1. However, changing the `autoScale` parameter to `false` solved the issue.

And as mentioned in the comments to this answer (thanks everyone!) it may be necessary to also set `useSystemTheme=true` so the `autoScale` parameter setting is respected.

Comment: what a piece of garbage that software is. But this worked for me on ubuntu 19.04 on the new update.

Comment: Just had the same problem on Arch Linux distribution. Turning off autoScale worked for me too.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks!

Comment: thanks, some problem. In my case, it only did this on my 4k monitor (which is not hidpi). Moving the window to a small monitor scaled back to normal. So auto-scale is treating my 4k monitor as hidpi based purely on resolution, I think. I reported this to zoom.

Comment: `autoScale` set to `false` but changed the scale factor to 2. Those two things in combination worked for me.

Comment: Additionally, I had to set `useSystemTheme=true` in order for the scale factor setting to be respected.

Comment: If the config file is empty, you need to make sure `autoScale=false` is under the `[General]` section

Comment: Worked for me too (on Ubuntu 20.04), thanks heaps!

Comment: In my standard installation setting useSystemTheme=true helped everything else was already set correctly. Maybe you could mention that settings as well in your answer as well.

Comment: Actually, just set `autoScale` to `true`.

Comment: I tried this with my flatpak zoom but I could not see any difference...

Answer (score 26):

The scale is set in an environment variable `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO`.

You can add it to the desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop` by changing the Exec line to `Exec=env QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=2 /usr/bin/zoom %U`

Or add `export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=2` to you profile script

Source: zoom.us support

Comment: Since Qt 5.6 the variable name has changed to `QT_SCALE_FACTOR`, therefore:
    `export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2`

Comment: Funny enough, this makes perfectly good working applications like Okular look terrible. Thus, I only added it to the `.desktop` file.

Answer (score 4):

In Fedora 31, installed from Flatpak, I edit `~/.local/share/applications/us.zoom.Zoom.desktop` as Ray Foss suggested above.

Before:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=zoom --file-forwarding us.zoom.Zoom @@u %U @@
```

After:

```
Exec=env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=zoom --file-forwarding us.zoom.Zoom @@u %U @@
```

Comment: Instead of modifying the `.desktop`, a flatpack override can be used: `flatpak override --env=QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 us.zoom.Zoom`

Comment: For pop users, path is `~/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/us.zoom.Zoom.desktop` for Pop!_OS 20.04

Comment: This is exactly what worked for me, but (a) zoom flatpak is installed system-wide at `/var/lib/flatpak/app/us.zoom.Zoom/current/active/export/share/applications/us.zoom.Zoom.desktop` and (b) it scales too big on my 4k screen, i.e. QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.5 is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The other options did not directly work for me, however Luke Hsiao's tips [1] did.

With a Flatpack in Pop!_OS 20.04, I changed my `~/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/us.zoom.Zoom.desktop` to include `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS` env in the exec line.
First I ran `xrandr` to find out my main screen is *HDMI-A-0*.

Then I prepended the *env* to the *Exec* line

```
Exec=env QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=HDMI-A-0=2.00 /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=zoom --file-forwarding us.zoom.Zoom @@u %U @@
```

If you have more monitors you can append their settings as comma-separated values.

[1] https://luke.hsiao.dev/blog/zoom-scaling/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `wayland` as your window manager you might want to run zoom in wayland as well. By default, it is xwayland.

The 2 advantages are:

1. HiDPI is scaled correctly with default options
2. The zoom window is rescaled when moved on a different screen (Useful with an external screen with a different resolution)

To enable zoom in wayland mode: `Exec=env QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland /usr/bin/zoom %U`

My `zoomus.conf` is as follow: `autoScale=true`, `scaleFactor=1` and `useSystemTheme=true`.

Answer (score 0):

> Zoom can be started with a proper scaling by overriding the `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` environment variable.

```
$ QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 zoom
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Zoom